# Resources for learning Joomla 1.6

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I've been about 2 months into Joomla 1.5 and there are a lot of great training/learning resources for that version out there. Now my web host has put 1.6 in as that the default/only installation via Fantastico and I'm have mixed feelings about it - it's good to be on the latest, but my 1.5 knowledge doesn't always translate to using 1.6. I'm getting a bit lost and the help files are not actually helpful.

Does anyone have any good resources (preferably video training and/or tutorials) on learning 1.6? Especially things like "if you did X in 1.5, you'll do Y in 1.6"?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an in depth article about migrating from 1.5 to 1.6 here:

http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial:Migrating_from_Joomla_1.5_to_Joomla_1.6

Official documentation for Joomla 1.6 is here:

http://docs.joomla.org/Category:Joomla!_1.6

Hope that helps.